# Can federated login (OpenID, e.g.) pose SQL injection risk?

Tags: openid, sql-injection, dotnetopenauth, federated-identity

Can all identity providers be safely assumed to sanitize user information, or could one create an account or identity provider to deliver malicious usernames, emails, contact lists, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trustworthiness of existing providers is **irrelevant**. An attacker can write their own identity provider and use that to send you whatever they want. You should practically never trust third-party data.

Comment: I should have phrased my question more along these lines.  Good to know.

Comment: That's exactly the same answer as mine an hour earlier below :(

Answer (score 2):

Never assume someone else is going to sanitise data for you. Do it yourself, or (better) interface to your database in a way that prevents SQL injection by proper encoding of parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Even if they do not allow such characters, even if the specification forbade such characters, you should not rely on that.

Make sure, when you receive the data, that it follows your expectations. Also, play safe and always use prepared statements/parameterized queries with no need for escaping the arguments or, if not possible, escape the query arguments. Do this by habit and you won't have nasty surprises.

Answer (score 1):

We have several people that have apostrophes in their email address, this is not invalid...the problem is not the apostrophe but that the coders are not using parameterized queries and or stored procedures. Really nobody should be using inline SQL and be concatenating string these days, that would prevent almost all SQL Injection attacks

If you do have to use dynamic SQL in for example SQL Server then use `sp_executeSQL` with parameters and not `EXEC`....

Comment: there are valid use cases for dynamic SQL to say that it should *never* be used is naive

Comment: where do I mention dynamic SQL before the last paragraph?

Comment: it is implied, you say using anything other than stored procedures or parameterized queries is wrong, the only other thing by default is dynamic SQL. Many `SELECT` queries that are built by ORM frameworks rely on dynamic SQL as the only way to do what you want. The only way is to build the Query string dynamically based on the inputs.

Comment: ORMs use parameterized dynamic queries,here is an nhibernate example 'exec sp_executesql N'select region0_.RegionId as RegionId0_, region0_.RegionDescription as 
RegionDe2_0_ from Region region0_ where (region0_.RegionDescription like @p0 )',
N'@p0 nvarchar(4)',@p0=N'zon%'1'

Comment: @SQLMenace Thanks! I'm pretty ignorant on SQL best practices, so your post points the way to some knowledge areas I need to expand.

Comment: @SQLMenace not everything is SQLServer based there are lots of frameworks that build SQL that can't be done with stored procedures or parameterized queries. Like adhoc queries where the columns in the `WHERE` clause are not known before hand, same with sorting and grouping options.